# Why Sharing Namespaces with Interface in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces

I have a large Project with an Interface for each class:

For example:

**Project XY**: 
*Namespace XY*-
Class A,B,C

**Project XY.Shared**: 
*Namespace XY.Shared*-
Class IA,IB,IC

Implemented

Namespace XY
Class A,B,C

Namespace XY
Class IA,IB,IC

**Question**

Whats the added value from sharing the Namespace with the Interface or is this just a Buisness Guidline ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "Shared namespace" but as far as those go, it depends largely on your overall architecture.

In an N-Layered domain architecture, I would for example use the following namespaces:

```
MyProject.Domain.Entities.Person; // Person class
MyProject.Domain.Contracts.IPeopleRepository; // Definition of my interface
MyProject.Data.Sql.PeopleRepository; // Implementation of the interface
```

In large projects, it makes sense to organize interfaces (contracts) and their implementations in separate dlls (namespaces). Makes it easier to understand and read what goes where

Comment: Ah ok thanks, I see this in a large project and havn´t seen such a thing before.